# How to add css properties to a div class based on another child div class?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have to apply below CSS only when this div class is available

**dhx_list_item dhx_list_day_events_item**

```
.dhx_view .day_events .dhx_scroll_cont:first-of-type:before {
//some code here
}
```

Pls find the attached.

Comment: Use javascript. You cannot use if/or/else in CSS

Answer (score 0):

With jquery, you could try something like this:

```
if ($('#child').length) {
    // manipulate the parent
    $('#parent').addClass('dhx_view');
}
```

`$('#child').length` will evaluate to `false` if none of the child `div`s are present.